# SQL COUNT ID by today, yesterday, this month, last month and this year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have below table

[image]

What I need, is to count the ticket_id created today, yesterday, this month, last month and this year

So I'm using below

```
SELECT COUNT(`ticket_id`) AS `total_tickets_today`
FROM `tickets`
WHERE DATE(`ticket_created_at` = `ticket_created_at`) ;
```

But I get total of 0 (even though new tickets were added today)

[image]

data created

[image]

This is my php code

```
//Get Total tickets today
$sql_total_tickets_today = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SSELECT COUNT(`ticket_id`) AS    total_tickets_today FROM tickets WHERE DATE (ticket_created_at) = 'ticket_created_at' ;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_total_tickets_today);
$total_tickets_today = $row['total_tickets_today'];

<p>OPEN Today:<strong> <?php echo number_format($total_tickets_today); ?></strong></p>
   <hr>
    <small>Yesterday: <?php echo number_format($total_tickets_yesterday); ?></small> | 
    <small>This Month: <?php echo number_format($total_tickets_month; ?></small> | 
    <small>Last month: <?php echo number_format($total_tickets_lastmonth); ?></small> | 
    <small>This year: <?php echo number_format($total_tickets_year); ?></small>
```

Comment: change: `WHERE DATE(ticket_created_at = ticket_created_at)`  to:  `WHERE DATE(ticket_created_at) = DATE(ticket_created_at)`    Otherwise you are comparing the dateTIMES....

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this query

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tickets 
    WHERE DATE(ticket_created_at) = CURRENT_DATE
) AS TODAY,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tickets 
    WHERE DATE(ticket_created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS YESTERDAY,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tickets
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ticket_created_at, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
) AS THIS_MONTH,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tickets
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ticket_created_at, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
) AS LAST_MONTH,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tickets
    WHERE YEAR(ticket_created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
) AS THIS_YEAR
```

Working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bb956c6712525ccd49df7425386cf0e)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(`ticket_id`) AS `total_tickets_today`
FROM `tickets`
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(`ticket_created_at`)) <= 1;
```

And then you change the parameter "day" in datediff and the value to which you compare the datediff to obtain the different values you are looking for.

Comment: Hey Benjamin, thanks for your quick answer. I'm getting this: `error in query (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'` Please note that i`m using mysql server on ubuntu linux if some different methods needed

Comment: What database service are you using ?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Comment: Alright, in MySQL, DATEDIFF automatically returns a difference in days, no need to put in parameter. I updated my answer.

Comment: I dont have any error now, but i`m getting the count of all ticket, like the DATEIF not filtering it

Comment: Of course, in MYSQL the order of the subtraction is the opposite. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, still not getting the right numbers of the ticket for the day unfortunate

Comment: To debug further you should select ticket_id and ticket_created_at, and you will be able to see what is wrong.

Comment: Still no joy! Still couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `current_date` to compare any date with today's date:

```
SELECT COUNT(`ticket_id`) AS    total_tickets_today FROM tickets WHERE DATE (ticket_created_at) = current_date ;
```

Comment: not working mate, thanks though!

Comment: First of all thanks for posting question with such details. Please let me know what's not working. So that I can try to help.

Comment: Doesnt work with your code, i get error format. Also, the code that Benjamin posted above, works only half way... it gives me the results, but the result doesnt reflect with the actual data